# How to solve an underdetermined linear system with variables limited to an interval

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

If I have an underdetermined linear system of equations, with the additional constraint that all of the variables are limited to the interval $[0, 1]$, what techniques are there to solve this in the general case? I would prefer algorithms with low computational time complexity, however I suspect that this is NP complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called a linear program and can be solved with most optimisation packages, if you have access to Matlab, [here](http://cvxr.com/cvx/)'s a simple and free one you can use.

Note: Linear programs can be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: Brilliant. As is often the case with maths, what I need is the correct terminology to search for. I do have Matlab, however this problem needs to be solved in the context of a larger application, not a Matlab environment. Now I can search for the appropriate libraries. Thanks again.